# JQuery UI DatePicker not displaying in Bootstrap Card

Tags: css, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a Bootstrap 4 site that I have created. I'm using Bootstrap Cards to group a number of questions for a survey. One such question needs a Date response, so I'm showing a JQuery-UI DatePicker, however when selected it does not appear.

I've added a second datepicker on a test field outside of the card, and this displays just fine. Additionally, if I "Inspect Element" and click the input field, I can see the calendar control, and I can see "display:none" being changed to "display:block", so all appears to work, it just doesnt show. I've tried changing the z-index to 1060 (an issue that apparently fixes it displaying in Modals, but to no avail)

Any suggestions?

The Card:

```
<div class="card card-default">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="card-title"><strong>2</strong> - Farm Resources</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-wrapper">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="">

                    <div class="card-title"><strong>Q4</strong> - When did you last soil sample?</div>
                    <div class="input-group col-md-4 mb-3">

                        <input type="text" class="form-control hasDatepicker" id="validationCustomUsername">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-title"><strong>Q5</strong> - How often on average are the fields soil sampled?</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        <div class="form-check radio radio-primary">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Q5" id="Q5_1" value="option1" checked="">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="Q5_1">
                                0-3 years
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check radio radio-primary">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Q5" id="Q5_2" value="option2" checked="">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="Q5_2">
                                3-6 years
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check radio radio-primary">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Q5" id="Q5_3" value="option3" checked="">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="Q5_3">
                                6-10 years
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check radio radio-primary">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Q5" id="Q5_4" value="option4" checked="">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="Q5_4">
                                10 years+
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-title"><strong>Q6</strong> - A question requiring selection from a dropdown?</div>
                    <div class="input-group col-md-4 mb-3">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                <option>Please select</option>
                                <option>1</option>
                                <option>2</option>
                                <option>3</option>
                                <option>4</option>
                                <option>5</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-title"><strong>Q7</strong> - Question with a slider?</div>
                    <div class="input-group col-md-4 mb-3">

                        <label for="amount">
                            Selected value:
                            <input type="text" id="amount" readonly="" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;width:50px;">
                        </label>
                        <div id="slider" style="width:100%;" class="ui-slider ui-corner-all ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content"><span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default" style="left: 20%;"></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>
```

The javascript initialising the datepicker:

```
$(function () {
    $("#validationCustomUsername").datepicker();

    $("#Date").datepicker();
});
```

Style for the card (should be bootstrap default)

```
.card {
position: relative;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
min-width: 0;
word-wrap: break-word;
background-color: #fff;
background-clip: border-box;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the class `hasDatepicker` from your input. That class is added by jquery UI after it has been initialized. Adding it yourself before the datepicker initializes messes things up.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#validationCustomUsername").datepicker();

    $("#Date").datepicker();
});
```

```css
.card {
position: relative;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
min-width: 0;
word-wrap: break-word;
background-color: #fff;
background-clip: border-box;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card card-default">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="card-title"><strong>2</strong> - Farm Resources</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-wrapper">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="">

                    <div class="card-title"><strong>Q4</strong> - When did you last soil sample?</div>
                    <div class="input-group col-md-4 mb-3">

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustomUsername">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-title"><strong>Q5</strong> - How often on average are the fields soil sampled?</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        <div class="form-check radio radio-primary">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Q5" id="Q5_1" value="option1" checked="">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="Q5_1">
                                0-3 years
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check radio radio-primary">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Q5" id="Q5_2" value="option2" checked="">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="Q5_2">
                                3-6 years
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check radio radio-primary">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Q5" id="Q5_3" value="option3" checked="">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="Q5_3">
                                6-10 years
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check radio radio-primary">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="Q5" id="Q5_4" value="option4" checked="">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="Q5_4">
                                10 years+
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-title"><strong>Q6</strong> - A question requiring selection from a dropdown?</div>
                    <div class="input-group col-md-4 mb-3">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                <option>Please select</option>
                                <option>1</option>
                                <option>2</option>
                                <option>3</option>
                                <option>4</option>
                                <option>5</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-title"><strong>Q7</strong> - Question with a slider?</div>
                    <div class="input-group col-md-4 mb-3">

                        <label for="amount">
                            Selected value:
                            <input type="text" id="amount" readonly="" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;width:50px;">
                        </label>
                        <div id="slider" style="width:100%;" class="ui-slider ui-corner-all ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content"><span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default" style="left: 20%;"></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>
```

Comment: sorry, I didnt clarify - this is the html as rendered in the browser - i.e after jquery has done its stuff and added the `hasDatepicker` class. However, I notice it is working in your snippet, so there's something messed up in my CSS outside of what I've posted, I guess?

Comment: Yes it must be something else then. All I did with your code was remove that class. I assume you have all the correct library's imported because you have the datepicker working in other places. The actual dropdown menu should get appended to the bottom of the DOM before the closing `</body>`, check and make sure it is there and see if its inline styles change when you click in the input

Comment: This worked for me! Ironically I could not approve it as an Answer; Sorry, Out of my control.